# Schema database with multiple category of user

Tags: mysql

I would like start a project for learn on best way how to create a good schema for my future applications. I'm starting having some questions about my project but for now I'm really interested to know how to make a good schema on this scenario:

I'm starting seeing that i have 2 main category, normal users and teams. This "trick" work similar to facebook where the users can create the own team and they can switch the proprety and get the control of them team.

Having 2 different profiles, user profile and team profile. I need to show posts,comments and photos.

So my question is:

I have to create 2 type of tables one for user and the other one for team? Or is better create a unique table and have just column with an integer for know if is user or admin?

example

```
table users -- user_posts
table admin -- admin_posts
```

or

```
table user --|__ posts // and have a column "type" on where if is 1 is user if is 2 is 
table team --|
```

Comment: Perhaps consider a hierarchical structure (within a single table) wherein `teams` are just `orphaned users` (users without parents). So then you're only concerned with users whose parent is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for the second option, allowing you more flexible development later.

```
table users
user_id, password, team_ID, etc

table team
team_id, admin_id (FKEY from user_id), name, description, etc
```

Comment: Yes i already set like that my table, but if then i want create 2 gallery one of user and another one of team is better have the 2 table like team_photos and user_photos or just one photos and have an id for know if is user or team?

Answer (score 1):

According to the team/group thing, you should create three tables:

1. users
2. teams
3. which user is in which team with which privileges

For 3 you could add kind of a enum with defined rules inside your project ... e.g. admin, editor ... you name it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but example, if i have to create a gallery, one for the user and one for team. what you suggest to do? one table called example gallery having `id_photo - name_photo - id_poster - id_type` where id_type if is 1 i'll go to search on the table user the corrispondent user on the column id_poster else if is 2 i'll go to search team with id of the column id_poster Or is better do 2 different table, example photo_user and photo_team?